# meteor test fails with SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Tags: meteor

when I run the command `meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha` I get the following error:

```
W20170314-15:20:44.067(-4)? (STDERR) /tmp/meteor-test-runfh1j93/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/znewsham_justplay-common.js:971
W20170314-15:20:44.068(-4)? (STDERR) import { Random } from 'meteor/random';
W20170314-15:20:44.068(-4)? (STDERR) ^^^^^^
W20170314-15:20:44.068(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20170314-15:20:44.069(-4)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
W20170314-15:20:44.069(-4)? (STDERR)     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
W20170314-15:20:44.070(-4)? (STDERR)     at /tmp/meteor-test-runfh1j93/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:289:30
W20170314-15:20:44.072(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20170314-15:20:44.073(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/danilo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_6.wp5fef++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20170314-15:20:44.074(-4)? (STDERR)     at /tmp/meteor-test-runfh1j93/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
W20170314-15:20:44.074(-4)? (STDERR)     at /tmp/meteor-test-runfh1j93/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:344:5
W20170314-15:20:44.075(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/tmp/meteor-test-runfh1j93/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:480:12)
W20170314-15:20:44.076(-4)? (STDERR)     at /tmp/meteor-test-runfh1j93/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:343:11
```

I dont get this on all machines I run it on, nor does it appear when not using tests.

I've tried reinstalling node, npm, meteor, removing the node_modules and reinstalling and installing babel-present-meteor.

I've had the issue before, but it either just went away on its own, or one of the hundreds of things I tried at the time got rid of it - but I can't get it working now. Any thoughts?

meteor version is 1.4.2.6
node is v4.7.3
npm is 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

The `import` and `export` words are part of [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-modules)

Can you make sure you have the `ecmascript` package installed?

https://docs.meteor.com/packages/ecmascript.html

Comment: I do - whats weird is I can run the project, just not the tests